# File i/o <> and & types

Tags: shell, io, file-type

I have this question from my programming class, we are programming in C++ and I'm not sure what the `<>` and `&` mean and are referring to, the question is:

```
process < grass > milk &
```

For the above commands to work as intended, what kind of files are `process`, `grass` and `milk`?

Comment: You should get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2513200) - this kind of things should be covered by any reasonable C++ beginners book. The keywords to look for are "templates" and "references".

Comment: Did the question ask what kind of *files* they were?

Comment: Is this something to be entered on a *command line*? With file redirection and `&` to run in the background? Or is this some kind of `C++` *code*? If it is the first option, this has nothing at all to do with `C++`, just basic file redirection using a command line program.

Comment: Oh, didn't even think of that - might actually be the case.

Comment: @crashmstr That might be it. Of course, that would make `process` describe the (simplified) workings of a cow.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is a *command line* to be entered on a Linux system,

- `process` is a program or script file that can be executed.
- `grass` is an existing text file whose contents are redirected to the standard input of `process`
- after `process` finishes, `milk` is a text file that contains the redirected standard output of `process`
- `&` tells the shell to run `process` in the background.

But, this has nothing to do with `C++` code.

Comment: Hey yeah i think this is _bash_ file redirection not _templates_ in c++! [this link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) might be a good one for him

Comment: The teacher didn't specify whether it was C++ code or linux command line input- I assumed it was C++ code because that was what the other questions were asking, but this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference (&) to an instance of the class *process* using as template *grass*.

You should study at least classes, references, and templates.

Comment: The question says what kind of *files* are they. Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: You might like to read more about [_files_ here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) _"On most modern operating systems, files are organized into one-dimensional arrays of bytes. The format of a file is defined by its content since a file is solely a container for data"_ I know a lot of this stuff seems obvious but it might help to think about it like _container for data_ rather than _file_.

Comment: @g-makulik When doctorlove wrote _"The question says what kind of files are they. Which makes no sense to me"_ People where looking at this like a c++ question which wouldn't make sense it's talking about a literal **file**

Comment: @g-makulik I realize that now :/